# Inserting Structs into a Linked-List Will not Appear as Correct Nodes

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, emulation, interrupt-handling

I am attempting to create a function which adds struct entries into a linked list but it doesn't seem to function properly. Using an input like so:

```
0       1     0
1       1     0
2       1     0
3       1     0
4       1     0
5       1     0
6       1     0
7       0     0
8       0     FF
9       0     FF
10      0     FF
11      0     FF
12      0     FF
13      0     FF
14      0     FF
15      0     FF
```

I get an output of:

```
Printing linked list...
dev:0
dev:0
dev:0
dev:0
dev:0
dev:0
dev:35
dev:46
dev:48
dev:61
dev:165
dev:200
dev:240
dev:254
dev:255
```

I am not sure what the cause of this is. I am expecting to see my devices (1-15) ranked according to their number. This module will be added to my emulator, to be used as a queue for pending device interrupts, so arranging my devices according to their priority is a requirement.

Additionally I am not sure how to retrieve the rest of my attributes, such as in_out and time. Should those not be a part of my list?

Why does my output simply have a list of integers capping at 16 bits?

Here is my whole module. Any tips or pointers would be great. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEV_NUM 15
#define addrbuf 64
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct entry{
    unsigned char input_output;
    unsigned char out_active;
    unsigned short time;
    unsigned char dev;
} entrystruct;

struct node{
  int n;
  struct node *prev;
  struct node *next;
  struct entry data;
}*head;

struct node* getnewnode(struct entry linked_dev){
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = linked_dev;
    newnode->prev = NULL;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void insert(struct entry linked_dev){
    struct node* newnode = getnewnode(linked_dev);
    struct node* temp = head;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
        return;
    }
    if(head->data.dev > linked_dev.dev){
        head->prev = newnode;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
        return;
    }

    while (temp->next && temp->next->data.dev < linked_dev.dev) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    newnode->next = temp->next;
    if(temp->next){
        temp->next->prev=newnode;
    }
    temp->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = temp;
}

void print(){       //Function purely for testing purposes
    struct node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("dev:%d\n", temp->data.dev);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    int dev = 0;
    char filecontent, file_name[15];
    FILE* dev_in;
    entrystruct entry[DEV_NUM];
    unsigned char* buffer;
    unsigned char* token;
    unsigned in_out, output_time;

    buffer = malloc(addrbuf);

if (argc != 2){
    printf("To operate on Linux enter:\n");
    printf("./<linkedlist> <devicefilename.in>\n");
    exit(1);
}

if ((dev_in = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
printf("Device input file %s could not be opened\n", argv[1]);
exit(1);
}

for (dev = 0; dev < DEV_NUM; dev++){
  fgets(buffer, addrbuf, dev_in);
  token = strtok(buffer, " \t\n");
  token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
  in_out = strtol(token, NULL, 16);
  token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
  output_time = strtol(token, NULL, 16);

  entry[dev].input_output = in_out;
  entry[dev].time = output_time;
  entry[dev].out_active = FALSE;

    insert(entry[dev]);
}

printf("Printing linked list...\n");
print();

fclose(dev_in);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't appear to set `entry[dev].dev`. It sets the other three items, but not the item that you're printing out. Also, 0 to 15 requires 16 instances in the `entry` array. In other words, `DEVNUM` should be 16.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109 . It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEV_NUM 16
#define addrbuf 64
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct entry{
    unsigned char input_output;
    unsigned short out_active;
    unsigned short occur_time;
    unsigned short dev;
} entrystruct;

struct node{
  int n;
  struct node *prev;
  struct node *next;
  struct entry data;
}*head;

struct node* getnewnode(struct entry linked_dev){
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = linked_dev;
    newnode->prev = NULL;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void insert(struct entry linked_dev){
    struct node* newnode = getnewnode(linked_dev);
    struct node* temp = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
        return;
    }

    if(head->data.dev > linked_dev.dev){
        head->prev = newnode;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
        return;
    }

    while ((temp->next) && (temp->next->data.dev < linked_dev.dev)) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    newnode->next = temp->next;
    if(temp->next){
        temp->next->prev = newnode;
    }
    temp->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = temp;
}

void print(){                                   //Function purely for testing purposes
    struct node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("dev:%2d input_output: %2d out_active: %2d occur_time: %2x \n",
        temp->data.dev, temp->data.input_output, temp->data.out_active, temp->data.occur_time);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
}
/*Testing mainline*/
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE* dev_in;
    int i = 0;

    entrystruct entry[DEV_NUM];

    unsigned char* buffer;
    unsigned char* token;
    unsigned short dev;
    unsigned in_out, output_time;

    buffer = malloc(addrbuf);

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("To operate on Linux enter:\n");
        printf("./<linkedlist> <devicefilename.in>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((dev_in = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Device input file %s could not be opened\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

    for (i = 0; i < DEV_NUM; i++){
      fgets(buffer, addrbuf, dev_in);
      token = strtok(buffer, " \t\n");
        dev = atoi(token);
      token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
      in_out = strtol(token, NULL, 16);
      token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
      output_time = strtol(token, NULL, 16);

      entry[dev].dev = dev;
      entry[dev].input_output = in_out;
      entry[dev].occur_time = output_time;
      entry[dev].out_active = FALSE;

        insert(entry[dev]);
}

    printf("Printing linked list...\n");
    print();

    fclose(dev_in);
    return 0;
}
```

I will be implementing a pop and clear function now. If anyone has any pointers that would be great. In any case thanks for pointing out my errors.

Comment: When it's all finished and working, you can post it over on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). The folks over there can help you with coding style, error checking, and refactoring for speed/size/readability. Best of luck!